# knitr: restraining from immediately plotting when do.call(grid.arrange, list_of_plots)

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, knitr, do.call

I have a two-rows figure which is composed by a plot on the first row and by a list of plots on the second row.

With `knitr` I do

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<plots, fig.width='\\textwidth', echo = FALSE, fig.height=5, fig.width = 10, warning = FALSE>>=

require(ggplot2) 
plot <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=cars, aes(speed, dist)) + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)

# create plot with function
makePlot <- function(myLabel) {
  ggplot() + geom_point(data=cars, aes(speed, dist)) + labs(x=NULL,y=NULL,title=myLabel)
}
list_plot <- lapply(c("one","two","three"), makePlot)

require(gridExtra)
grob <- do.call(grid.arrange, c(list_plot, nrow=1, ncol=3)) # here R sends the plots to the graphical device!

grid.arrange(plot, 
             grob,
             nrow=3)
@



\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

The issue is that I `do.call` my list of plots, which immediately send to the graphical devices the plots.

Is there a fix to this, either in `knitr` or by avoiding `do.call` to spit the plot when passing it to `grob`?

Comment: I think you should be using `arrangeGrob` instead.

Comment: @Axeman That's the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `??grid.arrange` we find the help page for `arrangeGrob`. This specifies the following:

> - arrangeGrob: return a grob without drawing
> - grid.arrange: draw on the current device
> - marrangeGrob: interface to arrangeGrob that can dispatch on multiple pages

The solution is therefore to use `arrangeGrob` instead of `grid.arrange`.

An added benefit is that a list of grobs can be passed with the `grobs` argument, so we can do away with the `do.call` construct.